# How to access compatible std::variant variants?

Tags: c++, c++20, variant

```
#include <variant>


struct A
{
    void foo(){}
};


struct B
{
    void foo(){}
};

int main()
{
    std::variant< A, B > v{ A{} };
    v.foo();  // doesn't work
}
```

How do I use the `std::variant` value not knowing it's type but knowing it's properties? I believe this is called Generic Polymorphism equivalent to Duck Typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Totally valid use case. I imagine there's many ways to do it, but here's one:

```
std::visit([](auto&& val) { val.foo(); }, v);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45f623bf0a3b5976)

The reason your initial code doesn't work is because `A::foo` is unrelated to `B::foo`, so to use them interchangeably you need a context where the type "containing" a `foo` member is deduced. In the `visit` example, we create such a context by making the callable a generic lambda.